# Create video from array of pixel values in C++

Tags: c++, video, cimg

Does anyone know of a method to save a sequence of pixel values, stored in an array to a video? Currently I'm using Cimg to visualise a simple n-body simulation, whilst I can save each iteration to an image file, this is very slow. Any suggestions on a similar library for handling video would be appreciated. Essentially, I just want to record what's displayed in the Cimg window I create to a video file. The program is written in C++, on linux, compiling with g++.

The fact that I can run the simulation and record it running with screen capturing software would seem to imply it's possible, but I'd like a tidier solution.

Answer (score 10):

I was playing around doing this today, and thought I would share my results. You can output raw RGB video from **CImg** and then use **ffmpeg** to encode it up into video like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
   const unsigned int width=1024;
   const unsigned int height=768;

   // Basic frame we will draw in
   CImg<unsigned char> image(width,height,1,3);

   unsigned char magenta[] = {255,0,255};

   // We are going to output 300 frames of 1024x768 RGB raw video
   // ... making a 10s long video at 30fps
   int radius=100;
   int cx=100;
   int cy=100;
   for(int frame=0;frame<300;frame++){
      // Start with black - it shows fewer stains ;-)
      image.fill(0);
      image.draw_circle(cx,cy,radius,magenta);

      // Move and re-colour circle
      cx+=2; cy++; if(magenta[1]!=255){magenta[1]++;}

      // Output to ffmpeg to make video, in planar GBR format
      // i.e. run program like this
      // ./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
      char* s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+(width*height));   // Get start of G plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+2*(width*height));       // Get start of B plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data());                        // Get start of R plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
   }
}
```

I guess I won't make it to Hollywood as the video is not very exciting!

[image]

Run the above code like this to make a video:

```
./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
```

---

**Note 1**

The thing to realise is that **CImg** stores data in a planar configuration, which means all the red pixels first, then all the green ones directly afterwards and then all the blue ones straight after that - all without any padding or spaces.

Imagine a 4x4 image (with 16 pixels) in CImg:

```
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

unlike regular RGB data, which would store the same image as:

```
RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB
```

So, you can either shuffle all the data around and reformat it and pass to **ffmpeg** as `-pixel_fmt rgb24`, or do as I did and output in **CImg**'s planar format and choose a matching `-pixel_fmt gbrp` (where the `p` means *"planar"*). You just have to output the planes in the correct B,G,R order. See also **Note 4**.

---

**Note 2**

I chose to do 3 `write()`s, one for each colour plane, for the sake of clarity of demonstration, it would be more efficient to use a *"gathered write"* with `writev()`, so this:

```
char* s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+(width*height));   // Get start of G plane
std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+2*(width*height));       // Get start of B plane
std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data());                        // Get start of R plane
std::cout.write(s,width*height);
```

would become something like:

```
struct iovec iov[3];
ssize_t nwritten;

iov[0].iov_base = reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+(width*height))
iov[0].iov_len  = width*height;
iov[1].iov_base = reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+2*(width*height));
iov[1].iov_len  = width*height;
iov[2].iov_base = reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data());  
iov[2].iov_len  = width*height;

nwritten = writev(STDOUT_FILENO,iov,3);
```

---

**Note 3**

I used the `-c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p` to make the video compatible with Apple's **QuickTime** on my Mac, but you can change the output easily anyway - the harder part was getting the interface between **CImg** and **fmpeg** right.

---

**Note 4**

If you want to shuffle the data around and write it to **ffmpeg** non-planar (`-pixel_fmt rgb`), I did that originally and the code was like this:

```
// Outside main loop
unsigned char* BIP = new unsigned char[width*height*3];
unsigned char *d,*r,*g,*b;

...
...

// Now output it...
// ... remember CImg is band-interleaved by plane  RRRRRR GGGGGG BBBBBB
// ... not band-interleaved by pixel RGB RGB RGB RGB
r=image.data();       // Start of R plane in CImg image
g=r+(width*height);   // Start of G plane in CImg image
b=g+(width*height);   // Start of B plane in CImg image
d=BIP;                // Destination buffer in RGB order
for(int i=0;i<width*height;i++){
   *d++=*r++;
   *d++=*g++;
   *d++=*b++;
}
// Output to ffmpeg to make video, i.e. run program like this
// ./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(BIP),width*height*3);
```

In theory, you can do this with **CImg**'s `permute_axes()` method, but I had no success.

Answer (score 2):

If saving image files is slow, you may have done something wrong. The cons of saving image files is disk space.

To produce video there are many choices:

- produce image sequences, and encode using 3rd party external tools like ffmpeg.
- use video lib, e.g. ffmpeg, libx264, gstreamer, DirectShow, etc.

On linux I strongly recommend libx264 or ffmpeg, they also provide example to save a video file from bitmap sequence.